# jquerymobile & php site to mobile app

Tags: php, android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I have created a website using jquery mobile and php. I was wondering if it is possible to convert this into a mobile app. I know of the software PhoneGap ( I have gone through this forum and this is what everyone suggests), but this does not support php. Is there any software out there where this can be accomplished with minimum amount of extra work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend makes this possible with Zend Studio, check it out: http://www.zend.com/products/studio/

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes this seems like it could work. Have you used it personally, if so, if I already have the code, how difficult is it to copy my code?

Comment: I haven't built an app with it yet, just discovered it myself and am looking forward to giving it a go. In my last project I used phonegsp with twig.is to render views with templates I converted from php and that worked well.